# How to create folder in file template for xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

friends i have created a file template , Is there any way to create folder in file template ? When i use Project template i can attache all things like groups , framework. but not with File Templates.

```
                    <key>Network Reachability/ISReachability_Wrapper.h</key>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Group</key>
                        <array>
                            <string>Network Reachability</string>
                        </array>
                        <key>Path</key>
                        <string>Network Reachability/ISReachability_Wrapper.h</string>
                    </dict>
```

Degault file templates has only files like .h,.m,xib. I have edited one of templateinfo.plist for file template. i succeeded in adding custom files by add new file. but i cant added folder(Group).

Comment: see so answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770398/xcode-4-how-to-customize-file-templates-and-project-templates

Comment: Thanks @Deepesh , but i already did that. and i already created Project templates and file templates. but my question is i can not create folder(group) by adding new file.

Comment: please create the folder out of the xcode and drag into the project and add the new file in that folder, check

Comment: humm, i am thinking about it. but it would be better that i can download it directly with file template.

Comment: Did you find any way?

Answer (score -1):

Just crate sub folder in your template directory, and then delete it by remove reference, add and from disk again.